# how can I make a web page (main). Where there are two links where each link sends me to a different project, using nginx and my domain is still https

Tags: python, http, nginx, https, gunicorn

> Nginx file

when it arrives in my domain/lala or poww redirect me to port where my project is running

```
gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_disable msie6;

upstream appserver {
        server unix:/home/sftpserver/projects/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name <domínio> <www.domínio>;

    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/ssl_certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/ssl_certificate.key;

    ssl on;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /lala{

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://<domínio>:8080/express; -- need change
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }

    location /poww {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://<domínio>:6060; -- need change
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

    }

    location @proxy_to_appserver {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://appserver;
    }
}
```

> HTML FILE

I'm new at doing deploy projects in the cloud, I believe the error is in the link where I go to nginx.
where is http: domain / lala or poww is not correct, I believe that through this link does not arrive in / lala or / poww of the nginx file

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        HOME
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <h1 class="bg-inverse text-white">
        HOME
    </h1>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="card" style="width: 35rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/castelo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">title</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">Alguma descriÃ§Ã£o aqui.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://dominio/poww" role="button">Visitar</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="card" style="width: 35rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img/empresa.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">title</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">Alguma descriÃ§Ã£o aqui.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://dominio/lala" role="button">Visitar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  This code is *not* minimal.

Comment: Your application do listen do HTTPS traffic? Have you considered using plain HTTP?

Comment: I need to use https for this.